# Deigning Cron Job System with K8S

Tags: kubernetes, cron, microservices

I have an issue with designing a system of cron-jobs. I'm going to build 10 cron-jobs each one has a specific task and may take many resources according to our daily traffic but it's all about memory consumption.

I have two options for the design:

The first is to make a repo for with node server running for each cron-job and make a deployment for it on Kubernetes with scaling pod vertically, and all pods will be in a namespace and will have its caching layer to be used in some jobs.

The second solution is to make just single repo with node server running and put all crons inside it and make a single pod for them with deployment and the pod scale vertically also.

But in the second solution there will be a single point of failure as if any cron job caused an issue and made the pod fail and the deployment will restart the pod and all running crons will end.

I don't know if there any other solutions, but I see that the second one has a single point of failure and will allocate lots of resources.

Comment: what is `node server`?

Comment: I mean node.js server